# compare data in text file vs avro file using python

Tags: python, python-3.6, avro

I am new to Python so please bear with me. 
I am using Python3.6.4 and I want to compare data in a text file Vs data in my Avro Dataset using Python. The data in my text file will be pipe delimited and would be coming from a table from a Relational database.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rebeca! Welcome to SO. Please write your code to let people know what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vikas. Here's the code below. Here I have hardcoded data being appended to the avro file and this is easy to compare. But my actual avro file output would be an output from a program and the text file would be an output from another. 
I'd have to compare those files. Thanks

```
import avro
import avro.schema
import avro.datafile
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

def writeAvro(fileName):
    schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("testSchema.avsc", "rb").read())

    writer = DataFileWriter(open("{}".format(fileName), "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
    writer.append({"id": 1, "name" : "John", "age": 34})
    writer.append({"id": 2, "name" : "Jane", "age": 134})
    writer.append({"id": 3, "name" : "Davis"})
    writer.close()

def readAvro(fileName):
    reader = DataFileReader(open("{}".format(fileName), "rb"), DatumReader())
    for record in reader:
        #print(record.get('name'))
        dict_name = record.get('name')
        dict_id = record.get('id')
        for p in expected:
            if p['name'] == dict_name:
                print(p)
    reader.close()

expected = [{'name': 'John', 'id': 1, 'age': 34},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane', 'age': 134},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Davis', 'age': None}]

#print(expected)

writeAvro("test.avro")
readAvro("test.avro")
```